# How to force select objects options by specific id in knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I have:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Type:</label> <select required="required"
                                    class="form-control m-b"
                                    data-bind="options: myListType, value: typeData, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>
                            </div>

 $scope.myListType= [
         {'id': '1', 'name': 'Block'},
         {'id': '2', 'name': 'NFA'},
         {'id': '3', 'name': 'FCA'},
         {'id': '4', 'name': 'ASIC'}
     ];


      $scope.typeData= {
        id : ko.observable(''),
        name: ko.observable('')              
    };
```

Now I want to force a selection on id 3, that is, automatically select by a specific id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up `typeData` wrong to be bound to `value`. `typeData` itself needs to be an observable. It does not need to have observable members unless you plan to update them individually.

```
$scope.typeData = ko.observable();
```

To set the selection, you just set the bound item to the value you want:

```
$scope.typeData($scope.myListType.find(item => item.id === '3'));
```